# Wordpress, Pictures not showing

Tags: wordpress, image, hyperlink

I built the following site over the weekend, and was pleased with my efforts: http://www.levieuxseasonnaire.com

The site showed perfectly on my Windows 7 and Linux laptops and also on both my android phones. I sent the link to family and friends and they have all come back saying the pictures are not showing in the website and blog page with the exception of the mountain picture on the home page.

I loaded most pictures directly from their url in Google pictures without putting them in the media library?

Can someone advise me on what I am doing wrong as I am at a loss to understand at present. This is the third site I have built using the same template but the first time I have encountered this problem.

This is an example of the image code I used

```
<figure style="width: 643px" class="wp-caption aligncenter">
    <img class="" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5PS2cQ-ma5cTr0AxmPgrsEfWqWWtwI6VQqgySF3WrUx3UpUWJj1I-FXz4ifea0cxuT5I9PlWuDsY1JzCLdjt59kZHyVlmX_U67_gkAgiq0dQBsZyeQ6UTr3aBSC3tur5i3aslQg0rpzzeactf6sZvE2apj7J8lQA6HpNmGXGUaB5Uro1dAtrvhK97nsxcHMBknMXzsXVRPtXATold3_f0L2J6y-1HSC7rR9ui39Ywu7sBiHi1N_0Ko-dzWQ0ZqziHt1oY5PgPRbQ4k7b8r3_pnLMWpeCe4oMwg4bBDwDtwcZQkDqgTlR6uF3g-tQBonyhs8e_fcTbROUfD1qAoMDjrSl1M3EhvTIc6EiGGXe0-UfGqqPun1KIpwXTqPocblRizBnlCdPyJMPOrq2rbUJE1jcEc2ALU8fBJZMFh7RgZMRgkRFUuIxulEW7Ga7zd2sPhodEtn-cytsWHDkZF_6VVu9HXqfoc91GtdQiPW5_0nbs2q00_p5xQQPMVpQQFQNfAEUEWRopUFNJvYJq76olQ8NZxJIiLVH4ULGsm7BnviiAdr17OACOr9NcaSQGTSG6L9o=s643-no" alt="" width="643" height="643">
    <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">
        My Bike (power) 1952 347cc AJS 16MC
     </figcaption>
 </figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not link to pictures hosted on other peoples sites. That is called leeching. Bandwith is money, and you are effectively stealing it from those other websites. It can be that those sites block you from leeching their images, it can be that you copied the google specific link instead of the direct image link. It's bad practise to link to offsite photo's without permission. Did you bother to google with the license type free to use?

For future strategy if you cannot upload the image to your own webhost, upload to a site like imgur.com who specialise and cater to image hosting.

Don't leech.

Comment: I am not leeching, they are my photos taken by myself for use on my website.

Comment: ah then I misunderstood. without being able to see them I just thought you found some pictures in the image search of google and implemented those in your site. i see that you uploaded them now to your own website :-) much better :-)